# Sum in ARRAYFORMULA based on possible cell values of two rows, then subtract another sum based on two different date values in two different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I really couldn't put the title into words very well. I will link a template spreadsheet below.

I've been working on a formula for hours now however I keep hitting dead ends. I'm unable to effectively do what I believe should be feasible. I'd give my attempts however I believe it would be of zero help, instead I'll explain my desired outcome.

I have a page with my employees, the E column isn't populated right now as I'd like to create a formula (ARRAYFORMULA so I don't have to paste a formula into each cell) to calculate the output based on a few conditions and values.

Vacation days are calculated as follows. The CEO gets 5, managers get 3 and assistants get 1. Extra vacation days based on points employees receive, 30 points or above is 5, 20 points or above is 3 and 10 or above point is 1.

Calculating the amount of vacation days employees have earned wasn't the hard part for me, it was having the formula subtract days based on how many vacation days have been used in the past 30 days.

We log vacations on the vacation page. The formula on the employees page needs to calculate how many vacation days each employee has used in the past 30 days only and subtract that from the total earned vacation days that employee has earned.

I'd like for the formula to use TODAY() to calculate 30 days in the past however for the sake of this example I'll use the date 06/09/2021 instead for continuity.

Sorry if I haven't explained this well or I'm asking too much in one go, I figured all the context is required.

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a50lNJ5iiBHjaA0ztwTmSl5g3Gwk1VlIWGm7ZVqyoHU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you make the sheet editable instead of View Only so that folks can test and demonstrate solutions there?

Comment: I've allowed copying of the sheet. Making the sheet editable to anyone who has the link would only get it grieved.